# Using images in responsive web design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

What is the correct method to use an image for different sizes. Like Thumbnail, Large Devices, Medium Devices and Small Devices? Mainly I'm using Bootstrap. I have used .img-responsive class. Is there any easy way to use the same image for these different screen sizes except calling different size images for different screen sizes? What is the correct common method to do such work?

Comment: To make the images flexible, simply add max-width:100% and height:auto. Image max-width:100% and height:auto works in IE7, but not in IE8 (yes, another weird IE bug). To fix this, you need to add width:auto\9 for IE8.

Comment: _“What is the correct common method to do such work?”_ - proper research. This is way too broad. A lot of stuff about responsive images has been written on the net already, so start doing some reading up.

Comment: For thumbnail, you need to specify the desired width and height of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same width for all devices. Place the image in different column structures for different window widths (desktop, mobile).

For example, if you want an image to be 50% width of its container on desktop, and then 100% of its container on mobile, wrap your image in a single div that contains both respective columns:

`<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">`

`<img src="example.png">`

`</div>`